# How to read a tab delimited values file with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, integer, csv

I have tried the following approach:

```
array = tdfread('file.txt');
```

The structure of the file is:

```
value1\tvalue2\tvalue3...
```

where each value can be -1 or 1.

Anyway the result obtained is:

```
array = 

   x0x2D1: ''
  x0x2D11: ''
  x0x2D12: ''
  x0x2D13: ''
  x0x2D14: ''
  x0x2D15: ''
  x0x2D16: ''
  x0x2D17: ''
  x0x2D18: ''
  x0x2D19: ''
 x0x2D110: ''
 x0x2D111: ''
 x0x2D112: ''
 x0x2D113: ''
 x0x2D114: ''
 x0x2D115: ''
 x0x2D116: ''
 x0x2D117: ''
 x0x2D118: ''
 x0x2D119: ''
 x0x2D120: ''
 x0x2D121: ''
 x0x2D122: ''
 x0x2D123: ''
 x0x2D124: ''
 x0x2D125: ''
 x0x2D126: ''
 x0x2D127: ''
 x0x2D128: ''
 x0x2D129: ''
...
```

I do not know where is the mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strange. You can try [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) instead:

```
array = dlmread('file.txt', '\t');
```

Also note that `dlmread` is a native MATLAB function and doesn't require the Statistics Toolbox.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out how to do it.. change separator to `\t` and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Francesco Ah, I've just noticed that your file is indeed tab-delimeted (I thought it was backslash-delimited), so it seems strange that `tdfread` doesn't work for you. But as long as `dlmread` works...